# The attempt to validate the provided endpoint resource failed

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Trying to create a new azure eventgrid endpoint subscription based on the code in the Microsoft tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-event-to-queue-storage) errors:

```
az eventgrid event-subscription create   --source-resource-id $topicid   --name eventsubscriptionname   --endpoint-type storagequeue   --endpoint $queueid   --expiration-date "2020-05-15"
```

> Deployment failed. Correlation ID: xxxx. The attempt to validate the provided azure endpoint resource:xxxx failed.

The tutorial says to ensure the account has write access to the storage, which it does, I am the owner. All properties in the command have valid values and I am executing from the azure cli.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird... I tried on my side and I have the expected result using the following commands :

```
$resourcegroup="your resource group"
$storagename="your storage name"
$queuename="your queue name"
$topicname="your topic name"
$subscriptionname="your subscription name"

$storageid=az storage account show --name $storagename --resource-group $resourcegroup --query id --output tsv
$queueid="$storageid/queueservices/default/queues/$queuename"
$topicid=az eventgrid topic show --name $topicname -g $resourcegroup --query id --output tsv

az eventgrid event-subscription create --source-resource-id $topicid --name $subscriptionname --endpoint-type storagequeue --endpoint $queueid --expiration-date "2020-05-15"
```

I sued PowerShell version 5.1.18362.752 and AZ CLI version 2.5.1